# What should be a Christian attitude to the Church of Satan?

Tags: satan

I've been recently watching documentary on LaVey Church of Satan and, I caught myself in a feeling that I actually envy a bit as those people were evidently having good and harmless fun and anyway had a good and understanding company.

What should be the right Christian attitude to The Church of Satan (I'm not talking of any other schools of satanism just of The Church of Satan). Should it be regarded as a crazy old-fashioned curiosity or should it be condemned?

Comment: LaVeyan Satanism has little or nothing to do with Christianity, and the Christian attitude to it should be more or less the same as the Christian attitude to any other non-Christian religion.

Comment: Agreed.  From what I've heard, LaVey chose the name "Satan" basically just to troll Christians, and it has nothing to do with actual devil-worship.

Comment: If the name of the church is an intentional heresy, it merits condemnation even if "techinically" the church has little to do with Christianity. A church called "the church of praising the name of the devil" would face similar problems (and for good reason!) even if it did not actually praise the name of the devil.

Answer (score 9):

Paul's sentiments towards the nation of Israel give us a good model.

> Brothers, my heart's desire and prayer to God for them is that they
>   may be saved. Romans 10:1 ESV

Our desire and prayer to God for the Church of Satan should be that they may be saved.  According to the Scriptures, they are living a lie, they are deceived, and they are blind to the reality.  People can certainly have "good times", but we were created to know God.

> In their case the god of this world has blinded the minds of the
>   unbelievers, to keep them from seeing the light of the gospel of the
>   glory of Christ, who is the image of God.  2 Corinthians 4:4 ESV

If we were temporal beings, then temporal pleasures would be our highest goal.  But we are not temporal beings.  Since we are beings with immortal souls, if all we ever experience are temporal pleasures, we should be pitied.  We were created to know God eternally and experience the eternal pleasures of that relationship.

> You make known to me the path of life; in your presence there is
>   fullness of joy; at your right hand are **pleasures forevermore**. 
>   Psalm 16:11 ESV

Hell will be no party or place of pleasure.  That's part of the deceit.  So, we should have great compassion and concern for those in the Church of Satan, despite any perception that they have good times or harmless fun.

Answer (score 2):

As a disciple of Christ, you should talk to them and explain the differences between the two religions.  Be careful to not become confrontational.

**Mark 12:31 NIV**

> The second is this: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no
>   commandment greater than these.”

It does NOT say, love them if and only if they believe what you believe.

---

It is not our job to judge them.  It is our job to enlighten them.

Comment: Talk to the satanists? I will, probably, be beaten then.

Comment: By whom?  If you think you will be beaten by them, then you misunderstand them.  If you think you'll be beat by your fellow Christians, then that's a different problem.  Of my study of other religions, I have yet to find a **religion** which professes hatred indiscriminately.  However people have used religions to profess hatred - and Christianity is one of them.

Comment: Possibly he would be beaten by the satanists. As I unterstand, their ethics is quite positive regarding punishing someone who annoys you against your desire.